# Ignoring base64 encoded attahments when grepping through .eml files

Tags: regex, bash, grep, base64

I've got a huge pile of exported emails in .eml format that I'm grepping through for keywords with something like this:

```
egrep -iR "keyword|list|foo|bar" *
```

This results in a number of false positives when using relatively short keywords due to base64 encoded email attachments like this:

```
Inbox/Email Subject.eml:rcX2aiCZBfoogjNUShcWC64U7buTJE3rC5CeShpo/Uhz0SeGz290rljsr6woPNt3DQ0iFGzixrdj
Inbox/Email Subject.eml:3qHXNEj5sKXUa3LxfkmEAEWOpW301Pbarq2Jr2IswluaeKqCgeHIEFmFQLeY4HIcTBe3wCf6HzPL
```

Is there a regex I can write that will identify and exclude these matches, or can I tell grep to stop reading a file once it gets to a line that says "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"?

Comment: In theory, nothing prevents an email author from putting textual content in a body part after a base64-encoded body part, although it's probably rare in practice, as email clients tend to expose a constrained repertoire of what MIME can offer.

Comment: I should have mentioned an additional requirement.  I'm actually trying to produce a list of filenames (adding -l to grep), rather that just matching content.  This prevents me from simply piping the output to another instance of grep and using an additional regex to exclude base64 encoded content as suggested by 
tripleee.

Comment: Just trim the output with `cut -d: -f1` (assuming your file names don't contain colons) ... or write your own special-purpose `grep` replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you exclude any matches consisting entirely of base64, you should be left with only the interesting matches. As an approximation, excluding any line consisting entirely of base64 with a length longer than, say, 60 characters is probably good enough for immediate human consumption.

```
egrep -iR "keyword|list|foo|bar" . |
egrep -v ':[0-9A-Za-z+/]{60,}$' |
less
```

If you need improved accuracy, maybe prefilter the messages to exclude any attachments. You might also want to check that the excluded lines are an even multiple of 4 characters long, although it's unlikely that you have a lot of false positives for that particular criterion.

Comment: I ended up using something like this: 
`egrep -iR "keyword|list|foo|bar" * | egrep -v ':[0-9A-Za-z+/]{60,}' | cut -d: -f1 | uniq > file_list`
I think it does a pretty good job of limiting the false positives.  The lawyers can deal with the few that it misses. :)

Answer (score 2):

You might find the `-w` grep option useful (match only complete words), although it will only reduce and not eliminate false positives since there is roughly a 1/1024 chance that a string in a base-64 encoded file will be surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters.

You can get grep to stop matching when it finds a given string, such as `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` but only at the cost of always stopping at the first match, by also matching that string and setting the maximum match count to 1. However, you then have to filter the matches:

```
grep -EiR -e "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" -e "foo|bar" -x 1 * |
grep -v -i "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
```

You could do this more easily and more precisely with gawk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1}
     /Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64/ {nextfile}
     /foo|bar/  {print FILENAME":"$0}' *
```

(Note: `nextfile` is a gawk extension. There are other ways to do this, but not as convenient.)

That's a bit much to type every time you want to do this, so you'd be better-off making it a shell function (or script, but I personally prefer functions.)